# When I create a Triggered Send I can't active it

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

Each time I create a Salesforce Triggered Send in Marketing Cloud Connect, I am unable to active it. If I follow the help steps (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_create_a_triggered_send.htm&type=5), I can't do step 17 (To begin sending the triggered send, click Activate).

After saving the new Triggered Send, I can only press Deactivate button, and if I do click it, no changes are made.

Do you know why it happens? It seems that there is a bug with Active field but I don't know how to solve it.

Could you help me?

Thank you,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if you have configured the respective OBJECT as in below link.

[Configure Trigger object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_configure_objects_and_triggers.htm&type=5)

For example LEAD object:

```
trigger Trig_Lead on Lead (after insert, after update) { et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Lead'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I did. It seems that there is a BUG due to the new Release, we can only activate new Trigger Send through API but only System Admins can do it but I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you so much for your answer.

Anna